# arm-thumb-elf-gcc: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable make: *** [main.o] error in Visual HAM SDK

Tags: c, gcc, windows-10, gameboy

I have installed visual HAM SDK for GBA development.I typed a basic program and compiled it then it gives me this error

```
    C:/gcc-arm/bin/arm-thumb-elf-gcc.exe  -I C:/gcc-arm/include -I C:/gcc-arm/arm-thumb-elf/include -I C:/include -I C:/system  -c -DHAM_HAM  -DHAM_MULTIBOOT  -DHAM_ENABLE_MBV2LIB -O2 -DHAM_WITH_LIBHAM  -mthumb-interwork -mlong-calls -Wall -save-temps -fverbose-asm -nostartfiles main.c -o main.o
      1 [main] arm-thumb-elf-gcc 11544 fork_copy: linked dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0xEDF000..0xEDF040, done 0, windows pid 22916, Win32 error 998
1138240 [main] arm-thumb-elf-gcc 11544 fork_copy: linked dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0xEDF000..0xEDF040, done 0, windows pid 7456, Win32 error 998
3304155 [main] arm-thumb-elf-gcc 11544 fork_copy: linked dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0xEDF000..0xEDF040, done 0, windows pid 6740, Win32 error 998
4333651 [main] arm-thumb-elf-gcc 11544 fork_copy: linked dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0xEDF000..0xEDF040, done 0, windows pid 16364, Win32 error 998
6448761 [main] arm-thumb-elf-gcc 11544 fork_copy: linked dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0xEDF000..0xEDF040, done 0, windows pid 20692, Win32 error 998
10565219 [main] arm-thumb-elf-gcc 11544 fork_copy: linked dll data/bss pass 0 failed, 0xEDF000..0xEDF040, done 0, windows pid 21388, Win32 error 998
arm-thumb-elf-gcc: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Here is my code

```
#include <mygba.h>

MULTIBOOT

int main(void)
{
   ham_Init();
   
   ham_InitText(0);

   while(TRUE)
   {
       ham_DrawText(0,0,"Hello World!");
   }

   return 0;
}


/* END OF FILE */
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same error today with this program oin Win10.
I've installed ad VM with WinXP and worked perfectly!!!
Good luck.
[HAM running on WinXP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YI4V.png)